# Don't know where to put the where in the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to make a `view` that find the top 5 highest quantity items from a characters inventory but also a column that shows how many other people also has the item.

- CHARACTERS

  - CHARID PK
- INVENTORY

  - ITEMID
  - CHARID
  - quantity
- ITEM

  - ITEMID

This is what I got so far,

```
CREATE VIEW vwPopItems --Top 5 most popular items
AS
SELECT TOP 5 INVENTORY.itemID, CHARACTERS.charName,quantity,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INVENTORY where INVENTORY.itemID =) as cnt
FROM INVENTORY
JOIN CHARACTERS
ON CHARACTERS.charID = INVENTORY.charID
WHERE INVENTORY.charID = 6
GO
```

It instead show `count` as all the records in that table without the `WHERE` so I need to make a `WHERE` where it only shows it for the specific item of the top 5 for the amount of characters that also has the item. know this what above is wrong but could you guys please show me what to do to fix it? :)

Comment: @Alessandro Ornano, Care to comment for rejecting my edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `COUNT(*)` instead of a subquery. Then use `TOP` and ORDER BY`to get the`TOP` 5.

```
SELECT TOP(5)
    i.itemID,
    c.charName,
    i.quantity,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM INVENTORY i
INNER JOIN CHARACTERS c
    ON c.charID = i.charID
WHERE
    i.charID = 6
GROUP BY 
    i.itemID,
    c.charName,
    i.quantity,
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, salary, department_id
FROM   employees E
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary)
                FROM   EMP T
                WHERE E.department_id = T.department_id)
```